# convert localtime response to seconds since 1970

Tags: php, localtime

I need to get the number of seconds since 1970 untill the time I got after calling `localtime`.    Is there a simple way to convert what is returning from `localtime (1393340639)` for example back to seconds?

Comment: Why are you using `localtime` in the first place? Why are you not just playing with timestamps instead of reverse engineering an time-utility method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `localtime`. Since PHP 5.2 was release, back last [November 2nd 2006](http://php.net/releases/#5.2.0), you can use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which offers a better interface to play with time, and which is compatible with UNIX timestamps (what you're looking for).

#### ** Edit **

For example :

```
// always work with UTC!
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// support your legacy need...
$lt = localtime(1393340639);

$dt = new DateTime();
// Note : DateTime's year is 0 based, while localtime's 1900 based, so we add 1900
// Note : DateTime's month is 1 based, while localtime's 0 based, so we add 1
$dt->setDate($lt[5] + 1900, $lt[4] + 1, $lt[3]);
$dt->setTime($lt[2], $lt[1], $lt[0]);
//$dt->setTimestamp(1393340639);  // <-- SAME THING!

var_dump($dt);
// output:
// object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
//  ["date"]=>
//  string(19) "2014-02-25 15:03:59"
//  ["timezone_type"]=>
//  int(3)
//  ["timezone"]=>
//  string(3) "UTC"
// }

echo $dt->getTimestamp();
// output: 1393340639 (which is your initial timestamp value)
```

You're better off not using `localtime` altogether, though. Just pass a `DateTime` object around.

Comment: @user1908466, check out my edit. You'll find your answer there, and my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for number of seconds from 1970 till a function being called, you can use `<?PHP echo time() ?>`

Comment: But that will give me the real time.
I need something else, I want to use `localtime` with a certain value, let's say `localtime(123456)` and than somewhere else, from the response (that represents a time from the past in this case) somehow to get back the number of seconds (123456).

Comment: oh! So `localtime( $num_of_seconds)` should return the formatted time of `current time - $num_of_seconds` ?

Comment: @user1908466 you are using `localtime` the wrong way. The function should only used when playing with date-time values, it is not meant to play with timestamps or otherwise. You should consider using `DateTime` instead.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. You want to reverse the result of `localtime()` function's result :-s